# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition not working with firefox 49. Its staying in loading status and not getting any response

Tags: firefox

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition not working with firefox 49. Its staying in loading status and not getting any response.

my scenario
1.Trying to load my page which is looking for current location
2.Its asking weather i would like to share my location 
3.I clicked always share my location
4.page is in loading status 
5.no response

Same thing if i manually ask to share the location before loading the page
i am getting resoponse

Is it some thing that firefox behaving differently than other browsers (chrome,IE)